# Hive change current_date format while using current_date in select statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table in `Hive` It is partitioned by `load_date`

Now I want to select data from this table where `load_date` is `today`

```
select * from table where load_date = current_date;

select * from table where load_date = 2018-09-26;
```

But the `date_format` I have is `yyyy_MM_dd` and `current_date` is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

How can I query my table using the `yyyy_MM_dd` near `current_date`

What I want is while using current_date in where clause

```
select * from table where load_date = 2018_09_26;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do like below

```
select * from table where load_date = date_format(current_date, 'yyyy_MM_dd');
```

This will convert the `date format` from `yyyy-MM-dd` to `yyyy_MM-dd`

Answer (score 1):

Using function in the `where` clause like this `load_date = date_format(current_date, 'yyyy_MM_dd')` will prevent partition pruning. You have two options: reload table with `yyyy-MM-dd` date format or calculate variable before using in the `where` clause.

This is how to calculate you date in 'yyyy_MM_dd' format in a shell and pass as a parameter to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date_var=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')
#call your script
hive -hivevar date_var="$date_var" -f your_script.hql
```

And use variable in the script:

```
select * from table where load_date = '${hivevar:date_var}';
```

And reloading option if applicable is trivial;